# Get list of Halal Restaurants Near me FourSquare API

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, foursquare

I am new to FourSquare API, So far I explore is that FourSquare is providing API to Halal Restaurants but I couldn't figure it out that how I can integrate into the App, Please some one suggest something or provide link to How to integrate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is "[Foursquare Category Hierarchy](https://developer.foursquare.com/categorytree)"

there you can find

Category: Halal Restaurant
id:52e81612bcbc57f1066b79ff

you need to use this [api request](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, This is what I am looking for, Do I need to call the Categories API or Venues API ?

Comment: Or should I use Search param ?

Comment: I think you can use search param.. :) , pleae accept my answer if it helped you..